Warning: Attempt to read property ¿Que hago?
Estoy trabajando con formularios en PHP, pero tengo un problema al momento de mostrar los datos que se van a editar en el formulario apareciendo ese error:
Warning:  Attempt to read property 
C:\xampp\htdocs\4CM1\departamental 2\Examen II\actualizar_datos.php on line 163

Así en cada una de las filas que tengo en el formulario, ya chequee el código una y otra vez pero no encuentro nada, aquí esta el código
 <?php
  //0 si no agregamos una mascota
  //1 si agregamos correctamente
  //2 si hubo un error
  //esta variable es para el mensaje a desplegar
  $estadoAgregarProducto=0;
  //if(isset($_POST['nombre']))
  //comprobar si los parametros estan en el URL
  var_dump($_POST);
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    require_once('db/config.php'); 
    require_once('db/conexion.php');
    require_once('models/producto.php');
    require_once('controllers/consultas-producto.php');

    $miConexion = new Conexion(HOST,USUARIO,CLAVE,DB);
    $miProducto = new Producto($id,"","",0,0);

    $consultasProducto = new ConsultasProducto($miConexion->conectar());
    $Producto = $consultasProducto->obtenerProductoPorId($miProducto);
  }

  //vamos a usarlo para actualizar el producto
  if(isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['descripcion']) && isset($_POST['precio']) && isset($_POST['stock']))
  {
    //para tener los datos del producto
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
      $descripccion = $_POST['descripcion'];
      $precio = $_POST['precio'];
      $stock = $_POST['stock'];

      require_once('db/config.php'); 
      require_once('db/conexion.php');
      require_once('models/producto.php');
      require_once('controllers/consultas-producto.php');
      
      $miConexion = new Conexion(HOST,USUARIO,CLAVE,DB);
      $miProducto = new Producto($id,$nombre,$descripccion,$precio,$stock);
      $consultasProducto = new ConsultasProducto($miConexion->conectar());
      
      if($consultasProducto->actualizarProducto($miProducto)){
        //redireccionar al listado de productos
        header("location:Listado_ferreteria.php");
        exit;
      }else{
        $estadoAgregarProducto=2;
      }
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Editar producto</title>
    <!-- plugins:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/ti-icons/css/themify-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/css/vendor.bundle.base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- Plugin css for this page -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/select2/select2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/select2-bootstrap-theme/select2-bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- End plugin css for this page -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- Layout styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <!-- End layout styles -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-scroller">
      <!-- partial:partials/_sidebar.html -->
      <nav class="sidebar sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-brand-wrapper d-none d-lg-flex align-items-center justify-content-center fixed-top">
          <a class="sidebar-brand brand-logo" href="Listado_ferreteria.html"><img src="assets/images/logo.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
          <a class="sidebar-brand brand-logo-mini" href="Listado_ferreteria.html"><img src="assets/images/logo-mini.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
          
          <li class="nav-item nav-category">
            <span class="nav-link">Acciones</span>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item menu-items">
            <a class="nav-link" href="Listado_ferreteria.php">
              <span class="menu-icon">
                <i class="mdi mdi-table-large"></i>
              </span>
              <span class="menu-title">Listado de productos</span>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item menu-items">
            <a class="nav-link btn btn-success nav-link" href="Agregar_producto.php">
              <span class="menu-icon">
                <i class="mdi mdi-plus-circle"></i>
              </span>
              <span class="menu-title">Añadir productos</span>
              <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- partial -->
      <div class="container-fluid page-body-wrapper">
        <!-- partial:partials/_navbar.html -->
        <nav class="navbar p-0 fixed-top d-flex flex-row">
          
          <div class="navbar-menu-wrapper flex-grow d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler align-self-center" type="button" data-toggle="minimize">
              <span class="mdi mdi-menu"></span>
            </button>

            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-right">

            </ul>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right d-lg-none align-self-center" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas">
              <span class="mdi mdi-format-line-spacing"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- partial -->
        <div class="main-panel">
          <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="page-header">
              <h3 class="page-title"> Editar productos </h3>
              <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="Listado_ferreteria.html">Listado de productos</a></li>
                  <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Actualizar productos</li>
                </ol>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              
              <div class="col-md-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Actualizar los datos de un producto</h4>
                    <p class="card-description"> Revise los datos ingresados </p>
                    <?php
                    
                    
                    if($estadoAgregarProducto==1)
                    echo '<label class="badge badge-gradient-success">DONE</label>';
                    if($estadoAgregarProducto==2)
                    echo '<label class="badge badge-gradient-danger">DONE</label>';

                    ?>
                    <form class="forms-sample" method="post" action="actualizar_datos.php">
              
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="id" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">ID</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $Producto->id; ?>" placeholder="Id producto" readonly>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Nombre del producto</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $Producto->nombre; ?>" placeholder="Nombre">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Descripccion</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                          <textarea class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" rows="4" placeholder="Descripccion"><?php echo $Producto->descripccion; ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="precio" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Precio</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="precio" name="precio" value="<?php echo $Producto->precio; ?>" placeholder="Precio">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="stock" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Stock</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="stock" name="stock" value="<?php echo $Producto->stock; ?>" placeholder="Stock" min="0" max="10000">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-2">Editar</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-dark">Cancelar</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
                
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
                
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
                
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
            
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 grid-margin stretch-card">

              </div>
              <div class="col-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
                
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 grid-margin">
                
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
                
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- content-wrapper ends -->
          <!-- partial:partials/_footer.html -->
          <footer class="footer">
            <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-between">
              <span class="text-muted text-center text-sm-left d-block d-sm-inline-block">Copyright © 2024 <a href="https://www.bootstrapdash.com/" target="_blank">BootstrapDash</a>. All rights reserved.</span>
            </div>
          </footer>
          <!-- partial -->
        </div>
        <!-- main-panel ends -->
      </div>
      <!-- page-body-wrapper ends -->
    </div>
    <!-- container-scroller -->
    <!-- plugins:js -->
    <script src="assets/vendors/js/vendor.bundle.base.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- Plugin js for this page -->
    <script src="assets/vendors/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendors/typeahead.js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- End plugin js for this page -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="assets/js/off-canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/misc.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/settings.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/todolist.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- Custom js for this page -->
    <script src="assets/js/file-upload.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/typeahead.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/select2.js"></script>
    <!-- End custom js for this page -->
  </body>
</html>

He intentado de todo, revisar el formulario, ver tutoriales, checar una y otra vez la base de datos y no encuentro nada, por lo que he visto el problema está en la conexión pero para ser sincero no hallo el error.

Primero, sabes cuál es la 163 que te está diciendo el error ?

Según parece en la línea 163 aparece esto: $Producto->id,  y el error te indica que desconoce lo que es $Producto y cual es esa propiedad.  Mirando tu código, veo que $Producto solo lo defines en el primer if(isset($_GET['id'])), y sin embargo lo invocas en el HTML exista o no el $_GET['id'], y de ahí el error que te aparece. Posible solución: Ponlo en el HTML solo si existe el $_GET['id'], o bien defínelo a priori como vacio usando $Producto = new stdClass(); y a ver si así te saltas ese error.

@masterguru eso es una respuesta xD

@Excorpion si tengo razón supongo que sí, pero como no queria comprobarlo lo he dejado caer a la espera de que alguien lo hiciera por mi o lo aprovechara para su respuesta :-)
